# Passing form data to a celery task

Tags: django

I have a simple form (with no model) in my views in which I capture the inputs the user type in order to send an email. I capture those inputs with:

```
if result['success']:
   name = form.cleaned_data['name']
   email = form.cleaned_data['email']
   ...
   send_email_task()
```

Te question is, how can I pass that data to a Celery send_email_task in order to send it. Something like:

```
@shared_task
def send_email_task():
   send_mail(name + ': ' + subject,
   'From: ' + email
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html), there are two ways to call a celery task **asynchronously**, `.delay()` and `.apply_async()`. Since you don't need to pass any special configurations, I would use a `.delay`.

```
if result['success']:
   name = form.cleaned_data['name']
   email = form.cleaned_data['email']
   ...
   send_email_task.delay(name, email)

@shared_task
def send_email_task(name, email):
   send_mail(name + ': ' + subject,
   'From: ' + email
   ...
```